# Confused regarding form protection (HTML, PHP)

Tags: php, forms, html-entities, html-encode

this will be so easy for someone.  I just spent 6 hours reading and I feel really stupid right now but hey... I'm learning so I thought - I'll ask you guys!   I've seen some excellent examples on here for other things so I figured... why not ask.  All I really want is kinda simple I'm sure...  I have a form, someone fills in data, I check it via JS for validity, I check in PHP for validity, I protect the SQL.  That all works fine.  What doesn't work fine is... if the PHP fails and the page reloads...  I have in the HTML the following which I'm sure some of you are familiar with..

```
<textarea name="comments" maxlength="1024" rows="6" cols="45" wrap="VIRTUAL" id="field_comments" onblur="CheckField(name, 1, 0)"><?php echo $_POST['comments']; ?></textarea>
```

The PHP outputs anything previously typed into the form beforehand via the echo...  Easy actually.  It works great because my JS and PHP USED to strip anything off that wasn't a-zA-Z0-9 etc.  My friend says I should allow pretty much anything to be entered and to escape it.  Ok, no problem.  I escape it but when I put a single quote or double quote (testing putting weird things into the field) and it redraws it - it keeps the escaped stuff.  For example.. I enter

'Dave' and I get back

\'Dave\'

and if I hit submit again.. I get...

\\'Dave\\' and so on...

Can I get it back to just 'Dave' in the form field without writing my own custom function to do that?  Or is that how I have to do it?

I have a sample test page showing what I was tinkering with if you want to see the example I made.

http://newmainpcs.perrycs.com/testForm.php

Any help would be great!  I tried undecoding them the  reencoding them... My main website is UTF-8 - the example doesn't really show my main site but I wrote this tiny testForm.php to try and figure this out!  lol.  I can do it in HTML or PHP.  PHP would probably be easier since thats where the heart of the actual REAL validation is since JS can be turned off.  I can give you snippits of code if you like.  But, I'm sure you'll get what I'm trying to say.

Thank you for your help!

David Perry
PerryCS
Perry Computer Services
(used to be an amazing assembly language programmer... this is what happens when you don't program for 17+ years).  lol.  Stuck on the simple things.

Comment: Better use `<?php echo isset($_POST['comments']) ? $_POST['comments'] : ''; ?>` or you will get a warning when the field is not present.

Comment: Depending on what level error reporting is set to

Comment: @Sam, it's my opinion and good practice to use E_ALL as your error reporting level and to treat all errors (even notices!) as fatal.

Comment: Hey there, I have E_ALL set.  And yes, I noticed in the beginning an insane # of undefined errors in the html section when it didn't take a path that touches them.  So I wrote a quick little function that just "touches" all the form field values and sets them to "" since the main reason someone is on the form is to fill out the form!  lol.  I do like your example of inserting a isset right into the echo... I'll keep a note of doing it that way on smaller forms!  That will save me a function!  Thank you!  I love ternary operators :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have either have `magic_quotes` activated, or you escape too much with `addslashes`. Use your database layer's quoting functionality instead, i.e. `mysqli_escape_string`.

PHP 5.4 finally got rid of magic quotes - something that you should do, too :)

---

I think your problem is that you are doing too many things to make your application safe.

You basically only need to:

1. Input: insert string into database, quoted with your database layer's escaping function
2. Output: `htmlspecialchars($row_from_database)`

With that, you're safe against SQL Injection (#1) and XSS (#2).

Magic quotes try to do the escaping in #1 for people who don't care about escaping input, but that's only half-hearted (magic quotes != db layer quoting) - it can be exploited, even though it's harder than without magic quotes.

## removing them

As http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php states,

> This is identical to what addslashes() does.

First, check if the are active with `get_magic_quotes_gpc()`. A true indicates your input has been escaped already.
Then run `stripslashes()` on the input variables you're working with.

Comment: The best is to totally disable [magic_quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php), as this (mis-)feature is deprecated and causes more troubles than it solves.

Comment: Wow, fast reply!  I can insert things into the database no problem using mysqli_escape_string - that works great!  What confuses me, is RE-showing what they typed when the form "fails" for some reason and I have to redraw the form.  It works great except if I use quotes.  Then I can see in the input field the slashes with the quotes when I really only want to see exactly what they typed.  Basically, I have a form field that's submitted to PHP - the PHP echo's out to the form what they typed.  I wanted it to look exactly as they typed it, quotes and all...  My example website shows the problem.

Comment: Not really... mysqli_escape_string does not do what htmlentities does.

Comment: I agree with you.  It's for safely inserting things into the DB...  for this example... just pretend... all I want to do is... take a form field, send to php, then have php echo it back out exactly as it was typed.  Quotes and all.  :)  I will check if my ISP has magic quotes on. (thank you)

Comment: It looks like one of them is on...
magic_quotes_gpc On On
magic_quotes_runtime Off Off
magic_quotes_sybase Off Off

Any way to turn that off?  I don't think my ISP will turn it off just for my site...

Comment: @cweiski Ah... I just got what you asked.  I was trying to turn off magic quotes but I have a feeling I'll have to use stripslashes.  I have some things to test... I'll let all of you know how it came out...  thx for all the tips!!!

Comment: @cweiske Magic quotes was the problem.  I used a test on get_magic_quotes - came back true, added stripslashes and everything is as it should have been if that wasn't enabled.  Thank you!  I've never been on here before asking questions.  So, now that my problem is solved - how do I fairly give credit?  It ultimately was magic quotes so this was the main answer, other people offered tips that would have worked if that wasn't on.  So, I guess I should credit this answer as the only answer?  Not sure how to fairly do this on here.  lol

Comment: Whats funny... if that wasn't on by default - I never would have run into this problem.  I had NO idea that even existed.  I didn't know something was changing my data without my knowledge.  I'm happy they are removing it.  I understand it had it's purpose to try and protect novice programmers - but it really caused a headache today!  StackOverFlow was the Advil for my problem!  Thanks for all the tips and solutions!   Much appreciated to all!

Comment: I generally accept the answer that solves the problem most thoroughly, and upvote it as well as others that went in the same direction. If other provide insight that was also helpful, I upvote them, too.

Answer (score 0):

When you output text into the middle of an HTML stream, you have to be careful to encode that text according to where exactly it is being outputted within that HTML stream.

For text being outputted within an HTML attribute, you need one encoding function (e.g. replacing `"` with `\"` etc). For text being outputted as the text content of an HTML element, you need another encoding function (e.g., replacing `<` with `&lt;` etc).

Comment: I also noticed I'm outputting right into a value="" field.  Maybe those quotes are messing it up... I'll do some testing.  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

To protect input in SQL, use an SQL escaping function like mysql_real_escape_string.

When you want to protect input against XSS (when redisplaying it in HTML), use htmlentities().

Also, check to see if you have gpc_magic_quotes enabled on your server using phpinfo(). If so, disable it in your php.ini file.

Comment: I'll check for that.  I'm in cpanel right now.  I have a feeling it will be quicker to just add phpinfo() to one of my files.. lol...

Answer (score 0):

Some basic code:

```
session_start();
if (!validated) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = $_POST['message'];
} else {
    $s = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['message']);
    mysql_query($s);
}
```

And then in your HTML:

```
<textarea>
    <?php 
        if (!empty($_SESSION['error'])) {
        echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['error']);
        unset($_SESSION['error']);
    ?> 
</textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'll check that out and see what I'm doing wrong...  I also realized that previously I was replying to the wrong people  thinking that a "add comment" would go at the bottom, now I noticed that it goes under each persons reply.  I'll be more careful in the future.